# Microsoft Graph oauth2 error AADSTS900144: the request body must contain the following parameter "grant type"

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Keep getting this error, I've got the correct redirect URI, clientId, clientSecret, grant_type and scope. I've tried as form-data, in the body, as url query parameters but I keep getting the exact same error. I've got the correct code, and I try refreshing it but to no avail. The base url is https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token.

```py
res = wrapped_post(
    MS_BASE,
    headers={"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
    params = {
        "redirect_uri": "http://localhost/",
        "client_id": clientId,
        "scope": "Files.ReadWrite offline_access",
    },
    payload={
        "redirect_uri": "http://localhost/",
        "client_id": clientId,
        "scope": "Files.ReadWrite offline_access",
        "grant_type": "authorization_code",
        "code": code,
        "client_secret": client_secret
    },
)
```

This is an example request. I've tried with files= instead of payload (for form-data), without any query params, with all the query params etc. `wrapped_post` is just a function used to wrap the requests.post function, with the same kwargs (payload instead of body I believe).

Comment: Can you show how you are making the request? JSON in body should work.

Comment: @juunas using the python requests module. So with just JSON in the body, and no url query parameters?

Comment: Can you show how you make the request in Python? You can remove the actual values of course.

Comment: @juunas I've edited the post

Answer (score 1):

grant_type=code needs to be in params

Comment: Not authorization_code? Also what about the other params/body/form-data?